# select....for update in hibernate query gives exception

Tags: java, hibernate

### how do i use select for update in hibernate ?

I wrote queries using it but gave me `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException`. is there any additional thing i have to set in properties for xml files?

I tried following

```
return getHibernateTemplate().find("select w.id.id, w.balance FROM    
Wallet where w.mobileNo=? and w.userType=? and w.accountTypeMaster.id=? 
For UPDATE",mobileNo, userType, accountTypeId);
```

Comment: `select w.id.id` should be select `w.id` You write `id` 2 times.

Comment: its not because of that wallet class has walletId class mapped in it